# tortoisesvn mark for comparison and compare URL result action

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

When I mark for comparison and compare URL with another tag in tortoisesvn, Change files show: some files action are normal, What's the 'normal' meaning?

Comment: I think it is talking about an actual change to the file versus a property change on the file.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question now, but the existing answer didn't provide the detail I was looking for. For anyone else who comes across this:

In TortiseSVN, changes are marked as 'Normal' in the comparison view when the content of the file hasn't been modified, but a property has. This means if you double click on the file or right click and 'Compare Revisions' *no changes will be shown*.

To see what the changes TortiseSVN picked up, right click and select "Show differences as unified diff". This should provide you with some information on any property changes that have taken place. In my case, the "svn:executable" property had been added to some files. You can read more about subversion properties [here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-propertypage.html).

Answer (score 0):

Normal means nothing has changed in the ( or about the ) file. It can be modified, added, conflicted etc. Also the status can be that of the "text" of the file or its properties and both are specified separately.